# JQuery. Как изменить стиль выделенного текста?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нагуглил метод `select()`, но все равно ничего не выходит.

```js
$("p").select(function() {
  $(this).css("color", "red").css("font-size", "20px")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Hello</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CSS::selection`, но он поддерживает только цвет текста и фона.

Вариант CSS:

```css
.moo {width: 200px;}
.moo::selection {
  color: #800;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<p class="moo">С точки зрения банальной эрудиции, каждый индивидуум, критически мотивирующий абстракцию, не может игнорировать поляризаторы утопического субъективизма</p>
```

А JS событие `select` работает только для элементов input и textarea. Даже contenteditable-div не работает с ним. Поэтому чтобы менять шрифт и размер выделенного текста, скорее всего нужно придумать какой-нибудь лютый костыль, который в зависимости от направления мышки будет динамически добавлять и удалять какой-нибудь `<span class="..">` из текста, который заранее будет содержать необходимые стили.

Answer (score -1):

Добавил класс элементу (не обязательно). **jQuery** метод `.select()` привязывает **JavaScript** обработчик событий **"select"** (срабатывает при выделении текста), или запускает это событие на выбранный элемент. Метод используется с элементом `<input>` (с текстовым типом `type = "text"`) и элементом `<textarea>` ([источник с примерами](https://basicweb.ru/jquery/jquery_event_select.php)).

```js
$('.example').on('click', function(){
  $(this).css("color", "red")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="example">Кликни и я стану красным!<p>
```

С использованием метода `.select`

```js
$("input").select(function() {
  $(this).css("color", "red").css("font-size", "20px")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <p>
    <input type="text" value="text" style="border:none; outline:none;">
  <p>
</label>
```

Comment: Видимо Вы плохо прочитали вопрос, минус к ответу.